# MySQL Query LEFT JOIN, COUNT, and SUM

Tags: mysql, count, pivot, left-join

This is my setup:

```
Emails_Table
|   ID    |    user_id    |   campaign_id    |   status    |      date     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  100    |       7       |        12        |   sent      |   2017-05-29  |
|  101    |       8       |        11        |   sent      |   2017-06-19  |
|  104    |       9       |        14        |   fail      |   2017-06-22  |
|  105    |       7       |        12        |   fail      |   2017-07-17  |
|  107    |       9       |        14        |   fail      |   2017-07-25  |
|  108    |       7       |        15        |   sent      |   2017-12-10  |
|  109    |       9       |        2         |   others    |   2018-01-02  |
|  110    |       9       |        17        |   sent      |   2018-01-11  |
|  111    |       9       |        14        |   fail      |   2018-01-22  |

Users_Table
| user_id |    username   |
---------------------------
|    5    |      john     |
|    7    |      james    |
|    8    |      maria    |
|    9    |      rex      |

Campaigns_Table
| campaign_id |     campaign_name     |
---------------------------------------
|      2      | Sample 2nd Campaign   |
|      11     | Sample 11             |
|      12     | Twelve                |
|      14     | Sample #14            |
|      15     | Lala Campaign         |
|      17     | Meow Campaign         |
|      18     | Cat GIFs Campaign     |
```

How can I get this kind of result? I am filtering using date range and the records are grouped by user_id.

```
Result
| user_id  | username | total_sent | total_failed |
---------------------------------------------------
|     7    |   james  |     2      |       1      |
|     8    |   maria  |     1      |       0      |
|     9    |   rex    |     1      |       3      |
```

My starting query structure is like this:

```
SELECT Emails_Table.user_id, username, COUNT/SUM(total_sent), COUNT/SUM(total_failed)
FROM Emails_Table
LEFT JOIN Users_Table ON Emails_Table.user_id=Users_Table.user_id
WHERE (date BETWEEN 2017-05-29 AND 2018-01-22)
GROUP BY user_id
```

As you can see, I have difficulty in implementing COUNT/SUM(total_sent) and COUNT/SUM(total_failed). Can someone suggest me on how to achieve this?

Comment: This transformation is called pivoting and has been asked and answered here on SO several times. The linked duplicate question has an answer that describes the logic to pivot your dataset in a step-by-step manner. Pls note that although it is possible to perform this transformation with SQL code, it may be more effective to actually do this in the application logic.

Comment: thank you so much. Yeah, I just realized this can be solved using pivot tables.